# Get an error with DevArt'sUniversal Oracle Provider but not with Microsoft's Syste.Data.OracleCleint

Tags: oracle, ado.net, devart

I am using DevArt's dotConnect Universal to connect to Oracle database.

It works very well in test enviroment and also on my local machine, but when I deployed it to production, it keeps giving errors intermittently. **These errrors are like ORA 12571: TNS Packet Failure and ORA -03114 :not connected to Oracle.** You can see these errors at: http://screencast.com/t/1XreLL0fq and http://screencast.com/t/mpbTkf3t4.

However, when I change the provider from Devart dotConnect Universal to **Microsoft's System.Data.OracleClient, everything works without any errors.** My code is exactly the same when using DevArt OR Micrsoft's Oracle provider, since I use the DBProvider style of coding in ADO.Net.

Why is DevArt's provider sometimes succeeding and sometimes failing in production ( it was perfect in test environment)? May be someone else has had a similar experience.

Answer (score 0):

We consider that both these errors ([ora-12571](http://ora-12571.ora-code.com/) and [ora-03114](http://ora-03114.ora-code.com/)) are caused by the Oracle server. And System.Data.OracleClient would produce the same error in a similar situation. Does the problem go away after you started using System.Data.OracleClient?

Try switching to the Direct mode when using dotConnect Universal: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?directmode.html (add the "Provider=Oracle;" connection string parameter to get a valid connection string for dotConnect Universal).